# How to stretch image in XML

Tags: android, eclipse

I have image with resolution smaller than device's screen. How can I stretch it to fit width but also scale height. When I change android:src to background, it fits width, but not height.

Here is my code:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/calculations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/calculations"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

**EDIT** : I tried it on low resolution device and it was small, but when I try it on my full HD device, it's OK. Why?

Comment: did you tried setting android:layout_height="match_parent"  ?

Comment: I tried, it didn't help, height is still same.

Comment: can you add complete xml code please ?

Comment: this is due to the quality of image if you want to add image in HD device then add an image which has more size and pixels or add this image in all drawables folders

Comment: But as you can read, on full HD screen small image is great fit, but on low res device, it's not stretched. Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Comment: yes that should be either way around what is the size of the image ?

Comment: 420x763 pixels, 32 bit depth

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set `android:adjustViewBounds` to `true`. What does this attribute do? Well, right from [d.android.com (click)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds):

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to
>   preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

So you're result should look like that:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/calculations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/calculations"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

#### Edit

So the problem with you drawable is, that its size is way bigger that its width. That's why there's so many whitespace in the landscape mode for example. See the following picture:

[image]

To overcome this issue you should set the `android:scaleType` to `fitXY`, which will stretch you image and doesn't keep the aspect-ratio, or `centerCrop` which will cut out a part of the image and keeps the aspect-ratio. Result would be something like this:

[image]

**Note:** I guess none of this is something you really want. So instead of using such a complex picture you should consider to create this via `XML` with `TextViews` and `Views`.

Comment: Yes, I did this, and it's OK on full HD device, but on smaller device it's small.

Comment: That's unlikely. The code tells the system to stretch the image to the whole width and keep the aspect ratio (increase the height as well) no matter what's the width of the screen is. Would you mind to post a link to the `calculations` picture?

Comment: It's true, same code for both devices. Sure, here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TiqaT8CdclU0FTQzdRX2IxbGc/view?usp=sharing) of image.

Comment: Thank you for your explenation, do you have any ideas how to fix it? I had it in textviews, but it didn't look nice and i don't like base font. This is how it looks on full HD device [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TiqaT8CdcldHQ5RlRja08zODQ/view?usp=sharing) and this on small device [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TiqaT8CdclQVNhR0tockx2SEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think a "fix" (in terms of doing this in xml) would go beyong the scope of an answer. Just as a note: You can use custom fonts in `TextView` if you're not happy with the standard font.

Answer (score 0):

try scaletype fitXY in your imageview

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/calculations"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/calculations"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:visibility="visible"  
android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: Same as above, works fine on big screens, but on smaller device only width is stretched, height isn't.